# How to prevent SKSpriteNode with physicsBody from moving when collided with other sprites?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have two SKSpriteNodes, lets say one represents a baseball bat, and another one a ball. Both have physics bodies, and the collision works fine, or at least detected. I have an SKAction that swings the bat, and it collides with the ball. When that happens both of them start moving. I want the ball to fly away, and the bat to stay in place. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try making the `bat.physicsBody.dynamic = false`, or make it so that bat does not collide with ball (but keep ball colliding with bat) i.e. bat's `collisionBitMask` does not contain ball's `categoryBitMask`:

```
bat.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~ballCategory // bat does not collide with ball
```

You'll have to do some trickery if you want bat to stop when it hits the ball (e.g. set up a contact between the two and when they touch, remove the action on bat and/or set bat's velocity to 0).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently it is very easy - there is a `pinned` property on the SKPhysicsBody, and I just had to set it to `true`.

Documentation states:
`A Boolean value that indicates whether the physics body’s node is pinned to its parent node.
The default value is false. If true, the node’s position is fixed relative to its parent. The node’s position cannot be changed by actions or physics forces. The node can freely rotate around its position in response to collisions or other forces. If the parent node has a physics body, the two physics bodies are treated as if they are connected with a pin joint.`

Comment: So the bat is moving realisticly i.e like it's being held at one end and swung?

Comment: Yes, the only thing is that it gets pinned at the center point by default. So you'd have to adjust your anchor point and physics body's frame.